# Debian with nginx docker image won't update

Tags: docker, nginx, debian, dockerfile

I'm bulding nginx in a Debian-based docker image. Every time I run it, it shows me the current nginx version nginx/1.10.3. I need it to download the latest stable nginx.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get install -yq gnupg2
RUN apt-get install -yq software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -yq lsb-release
RUN apt-get install -yq curl

RUN add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
RUN add-apt-repository "deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian `lsb_release -cs` nginx"

RUN apt-get install -y nginx

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, trivially, you need to `apt-get update` to fetch the index files from the repos you added before `apt` will find any packages there.

```
RUN add-apt-repository blah blah
RUN apt-get update -y   # Add this
RUN apt-get install -y whatever
```

But also, you have invalid repos in the `add-apt-repository` section.  The output of `lsb_release -sc` is a Debian code name like `stretch` which of course the Canonical partner repo doesn't have a section for; and [the NGninx repo only supports Debian `squeeze`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/) (though I would expect the packages to also work on newer versions of Debian).

Finally, you need to manage the keys of these repos, or otherwise mark them as safe. As a small bonus, I tried to condense your `apt-get` downloads slightly.  Try this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -yq gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common curl # lsb-release

# XXX FIXME: the use of [trusted=yes] is really quick and dirty
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner"
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [trusted=yes] http://nginx.org/packages/debian squeeze nginx"

RUN apt-get update -y    
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/

RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx"]
```

Comment: it tells me an error (add-apt-repository returned a non-zero code)

Comment: That's a flaw in your original Dockerfile then, not in this addition.

Comment: As an aside, probably replace the backticks with a modern command substitution like you have on the previous line.

Comment: is there any other way that i can get the latest stable nginx when i build the Dockerfile ? even if it is on another distro image ... all i need is a dockerfile that installs nginx latest stable every time i run it

Comment: Find a repo which isn't broken ...? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/ only seems to have a repo for Debian Squeeze which is way obsolete, but it should probably work just fine for newer versions as well.

Comment: still the same error ... can you recommend me a dockerfile with nginx stable ?

Comment: finished successfully but the version of nginx is still nginx/1.10.3 :(

Comment: Because the `nginx` repo offers 10.8 which is a lower version number. Find a repo which actually features the build you want to use.

Comment: i know i'm making this long sorry but i downloaded a new image based on debian:stretch-slim it worked with the latest version ... do you know a way that i can add vts module to it ?

Comment: This is straying way off topic for this question. Maybe accept one of the answers here (or post one of your own and accept that) and then ask a new question. But this is really stretching it for Stack Overflow -- maybe try one of our sibling sites like [su] or [unix.se] instead, but read their posting guidelines (too) before posting there.

Answer (score 1):

Docker image layers serve as a cache for subsequent builds. Without some sort of change in the Dockerfile, you're likely getting nginx 1.10.3 because it was cached from a previous build.

Instead of building your own nginx image, you should use the official [nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), and choose the tag (e.g., `1.15.9`) for the version you want.

Comment: how can i add a new repository so nginx will be downloaded from it ? i nned the latest version in a docker image so i can add vts module to it

Comment: Like this answer says, don't; instead, use the official `nginx` Docker image and take it from there.